# Strange error with QListWidgetItem that uses QIcon

Tags: qt, boost, qt4, icons, qlistwidget

I am building up a QListWidget, browsing through a directory so that every ".png" gets listed with a preview icon.

The core of my populating loop looks like this:

```
new QListWidgetItem( QIcon(act_fullname), act_filename);
```

Right after the whole list is ready, the app crashes.
The error is many times repeated and says this:

> On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the
>   same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt
>   binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of
>   binaries are being loaded. QObject::moveToThread: Current thread
>   (0x103339cb0) is not the object's thread (0x10a848670). Cannot move to
>   target thread (0x103339cb0)
>
> On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the
>   same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt
>   binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of
>   binaries are being loaded.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

If I skip the icons there is no problem. I have also tried going

```
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(act_filename);
ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
item->setIcon(QIcon(act_fullname));
```

and got no difference.

EDIT 2:

I do not call `QObject::moveToThread(QThread*)` I don't even use threads (deliberately at least).

Also, the errors appear to come after the loop. I have cout-ed every iteration and the end of the loop and right after my "end loop cout msg" I see that

> objc[56963]: Class QCocoaColorPanelDelegate is implemented in both
>   /Users/Barnabas/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
>   and
>   /Users/Barnabas/Programming/Qt/demo_OpenCV-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/demo_OpenCV.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Here, too, I do not use QCocoaColorPanelDelegate. I don't even know what it is ... :(

But here is my more detailed code:

```
boost::filesystem::path p("/path/to/dir");
if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(p))
{
    for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(p); it!=boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->path().extension().string()==".png")
        {
            std::cout<< it->path() <<std::endl;
            QString item_name( it->path.stem().c_str() );
            QString screen_file( it->path.c_str() );
            QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(item_name);
            QIcon *icon = new QIcon(screen_file);
            item->setIcon(*icon); // if I comment this one out, everything is fine.
            ui->imageList->addItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tested it with a single .png and the image was displayed properly in the list but crash followed with the very same messages.

Comment: Does `QIcon(act_fullname)` generate this error or `item->setIcon(icon)`?

Comment: Show us your code where you call `QObject::moveToThread(QThread*)`.

Comment: Thanks for the questions! Added details as requested.

Comment: Well, I have boost_system-mt and boost_filesystem-mt linked. Could that be at the core of the issue? I do not have boost libs without mt and I would not go down that line either.

Comment: Did you try this "Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded"?

Comment: Im sorry but Im a newbie. You mean I should add "DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1" to the .pro file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution: manually removed the Debug and the Release directories.
For those whose similar problem is not solved by this see: [this link](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-38206.html).